# ReferenceError: variable is not defined (but defined)

Tags: referenceerror

Consoles say: "ReferenceError: tpyeRand is not defined" (at line "else if")

```
var type;
var typeRand = Math.random();
typeRand = 0.5;
alert(typeRand);
if(typeRand < 0.7) {
  type = "calm";
}
else if(tpyeRand < 0.9) {
  type = "fuzzy";
}
else {
  type = "angry";
}
```

Comment: Is this any particular language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just misspelled the word "typeRand" on that line.